# how do I count numbers from command line?

Tags: shell

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
```

Let's say I have a file contains these numbers, I want to count those numbers like this

(num):(occurence)

```
1:3
2:3
3:2
```

How do I do this in shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this

```
    sort a.dat | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, ":", $1}'
```

If you really bothered by the white space

```
   sort a.dat | uniq -c | awk '{print $2":"$1}'
```

Comment: Or just awk '{ print $2":"$1 }'

Answer (score 0):

Just awk:

```
awk '!a[$0]++{b[++i]=$0}END{for(i=1;i in b;++i)print b[i]":"a[b[i]]}' file
```

Output:

```
1:3
2:3
3:2
```